# Windows Azure - a common data access layer?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I've been working through [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/1-overview/) tutorial to get started with cloud services in Azure.

The project has one web role and two worker roles, and they share similar code for accessing the storage tables. Could I have a common data access layer shared between them? Would I create a separate role for this? I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but is that what you want? Sharing the same access layer, all services will access the same database.

You just need to add a Nuget Package Windows Azure Storage and access your storage account / blobs, tables, queues...